# Xcode 13.2 - Adding package hangs on "Preparing to validate"

Tags: swift, xcode

I have recently updated to Xcode 13.2 from the Mac App Store. While trying to fix an issue with a Swift package, I uninstalled it and now I cannot reinstall the package.

When I try to add a package from GitHub the process hangs immediately on "Preparing to validate".

I already attempted to restart Xcode, restart my mac, clean derived data, reset Swift package caches and update package versions to no avail.

Is there any way around this issue?[image: Screenshot of issue]

Comment: I updated Xcode 13.2 and try to use the Swift package for the first time instead of pods... and this happened ... I thought I have done something wrong...

Comment: I've used the Package manager several times in the last year, and it works great. But, yeah, something is wrong with this iteration. Please fix it soon!

Comment: Seeing the same on 14.0.1

Comment: Yearly fall update: Still happens under 15.0.1, which on this computer refuses to validate any packages whatsoever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to update Xcode to 13.2.1

They have just released the update that should fix it. See in the link that @mikeyh posted in the other answer: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696504.

Comment: The accepted solution for that Developer Forums post — update to 13.2.1 — hasn't relieved the problem for me.

Answer (score 18):

Check https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696504 and re-download Xcode 13.2 directly from the releases section of the Apple Developer website: https://developer.apple.com/download/release/

Answer (score 5):

I'm on Xcode 13.4.1 and ran into this same problem when trying to convert my project from CocoaPods to SPM packages because I was using the **Legacy Build Location** setting. When trying to install any package it would immediately hang on "Preparing to validate..." just like in the screenshot of the question.

I did get an error stating something like *the package could not be added because of using the Legacy Build Location setting*, however I did not notice this in the Issue Navigator for a while because once I removed all of my CocoaPods and before I could add the SPM packages I was getting hundreds of build errors.

To fix (if your project can use the default Build Location setting) is to set it by going to
`File->Project Settings...->Advanced...->Xcode Default`

[image: Advanced project settings]

Comment: I had to check legacy, check this build location, clean derived data, close & reopen xcode a few times... and finally it worked. In one project (other projects imported same package without trouble) 13.4.1

Comment: Thank you! I'm confident that this saved me hours