# xcode stuck when adding a package

Tags: xcode

On xcode 13.2 this is what's happens when I try to add a package:

[image: Stuck XCode]

Yes, xcode stay stuck forever with this popup.

Fresh xcode project, fresh xcode install; this happens with any Swift Package.

Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: This might be the same issue everyone is having right now: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696504 . **"To workaround this issue, please re-download Xcode 13.2 directly from Releases section of the [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/download/release/) website."**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode 13.2 - Adding package hangs on "Preparing to validate"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70342833/xcode-13-2-adding-package-hangs-on-preparing-to-validate)